# How to submit a null value in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I am designing a search page in MVC4, C#. I have the following search form in my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Vragen", FormMethod.Get)) { 
 <div id="advanced">
    <h1 name="advanced">
        <span>Geavanceerd zoeken</span>
    </h1>
    <div class="green">
        <span>
            <input placeholder="Trefwoord" class="geav" type="text" name="tref" id="textfield" /><br />
            <input placeholder="Politicus" class="geav" type="text" name="pol" id="textfield" /><br />
        </span>
        <span>
            <select class="geav" name="partijId">
                <option value="">-Partij-</option>

                @foreach (var partij in partijen) { 
                    <option value="@partij.partijID">@partij.naam</option>
                }
            </select> 
            <br />
            <select class="geav" name="parlementId">
                <option value="">-Niveau-</option>

                @foreach (var parlement in parlementen) {
                    <option value="@parlement.parlementID">@parlement.naam</option> 
                }
            </select> 

        </span>
        <span>
            <select class="geav" name="themaId">
                <option value="">-Thema-</option>

                @foreach (var thema in themas) { 
                    <option value="@thema.themaID">@thema.naam</option>

                    List<Subthema> subthemas = themaMapper.getAlleSubthemas(thema.themaID);

                    foreach (var subthema in subthemas) { 
                        <option value="@subthema.subthemaID">@subthema.naam</option>
                    }
                }
            </select>
    ...
```

This is not the whole form, If I submit this to my `searchcontroller` with **empty (= default values "")**, the url comes out like this:
`localhost:62488/Vragen/Search?tref=test&pol=&partijId=&parlementId=&themaId=&kieskringId=`

with empty variables (note `pol=$partijId=&...`)
I want these values to disapear when they are left blank (so I have `null` values)... how can I do this?

Comment: use f0om method post instead..

Comment: The only solution I can think of is with some javascript black magic. Do you really need this feature?

Comment: I need this feature because for some reason I can't get a "" from the url values... with viewcontext.values.. using post didn't seem to work Ehsan, that removes all the parameters, even the ones filled in

Answer (score 0):

The way to get what you want is to receive a *model* instead of individual values in your action. Just build a class like this:

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public string tref { get; set; }
    public string pol { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

and then in your action do this:

```
public ActionResult Search(SearchModel model)
```